# Как передать в конструктор класса список аргументов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Пример есть сги-ые числа как посчитать `getDiameter` для каждого числа?

```
class Ccircle():
    def __init__ (self,r):
        self.r = r

    def getSquare(self):
        return pi*(self.r**2)

    def getDiameter(self):
         return self.r*2 

    def getPerimeter(self):
        return pi*self.getDiameter()


myArray = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0,4 )]
myArray.sort()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Ccircle(randint(0, 9)).getDiameter() for _ in range(4)]
```